# Avoiding Zends Error Messages

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter

I am using the Zend Framework for ACL's in codeigniter but if something is not right in the database or there is an error with the code that interfaces with the framework then the framework displays its own error messages. Is there a way to suppress these?

Comment: Its own error messages? Are you referring to exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to exceptions, use something like this:

```
try {
  $acl = new Zend_Acl();
  // some other Zend_* stuff
} catch(Zend_Exception $e) {
  // handle the error (the thrown exception) your way
}
```